# Error when try writing to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I try `df.to_excel()` and get error
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 175: invalid continuation byte`.
Next I try `df.to_excel(encoding='utf-8')`, but error didn't dissapear/
What's wrong?

Comment: it would be easier if you just post the part of the code that seem to be causing the issues.

Comment: Are you using python 2? What's your `sys.getdefaultencoding()` say? Note it's a **decode** error. Probably at some point something is calling `.encode('utf8')` on a byte-string that contains some other encoding, as python 2 then implicitly first tries to `.decode()`. Please include a minimal example of what you're doing and the full traceback you get.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, it return 'ascii'

Comment: try `encoding='cp1251'` ...

Comment: @MaxU, It doesn't help. I try convert strings to `latin` also, `search_val = dict2['text'][0].encode('latin1')` and it returns this error too

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("latin-1")
```

Failing that, try `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`